# Editor extension onDidCloseTerminal() causes editor to freeze

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write an extension for vscode, and I am trying to handle closing of the terminal, but whenever I click on the trash on the terminal to delete the terminal, the editor freezes. Here is how I am handling how the editor is closed. Am I doing something wrong?

I have multiple terminals, and I am opening one that is not named `Server Terminal`, it is called `Add Package` so it doesn't go into the `if` statement which is what I want in this case. So, what is causing the editor to freeze? I tried adding an `else { t.dispose() }` but the editor still freezes.

```js
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    window.onDidCloseTerminal(t => {
        // Watch for when the server terminal closes.
        if (t.name === 'Server Terminal') {
            Serve.server = undefined
            showMessage(`The server has been stopped on "http://${Serve.host}:${Serve.port}"`)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If you are on Windows OS, there's a known bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76548

Comment: I actually found what was causing this for me. I was able to stop this from happening by killing the process that was running in the terminal in that callback

Comment: By doing this, it seems to fix the issue: `const id = await terminal.processId; id && kill(id)`

Answer (score 0):

So, for me, it seems as if to solve this issue I need to first kill the process manually, then I can set `Serve.server` to `undefined`. This seems to solve the issue of the editor freezing:

```
window.onDidCloseTerminal(async t => {
    // Watch for when the server terminal closes.
    if (t.name === 'Server Terminal') {
        const id = await t.processId 
        id && kill(id)
        Serve.server = undefined
    }
})
```